# VPN Router + Tor and 2nd VPN Local Machine Clarifications

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vpn, encryption

Hello my question is I have my router configured to connect through a vpn (VPN A). Thus all Internet traffic on my network goes through a vpn. If I run tor on a local machine with a 2nd vpn (VPN B), does this cause vpn b to create a tunnel within the tunnel create by vpn a? Also does the tor browser still successfully give me anonymity with this setup? I'm trying to figure out if the two vpns will work together to give me a double layer of encryption along with tors anonymity.

Any suggestions for the above setup are appreciated.